# Insert data in a table

Tags: php

I have this code to select and output data from database

```
<?php

require('system/connect.php'); //load the connection file

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `movie`"); // add mysql code to a variable. In this case it will    select ALL columns from the database.

$query = mysql_query($sql); //run the query contained within the variable.

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //store each single row from the database in an array named $row. While there are any rows left, loop through and execute the following code:

$id = $row['movie_id']; //gets name from DB for a single row
$name = $row['movie_name']; //gets age from DB for a single row
$category = $row['movie_category']; //gets age from DB for a single row

//Following code outputs the data to the webpage:

echo $id;

echo $name;

echo $category;
};
?>
```

The page show: 1titanicromance2zoroaction3blood diamondsaction

I need a way to make a table or array and to insert data directly to it.

Comment: Well, you could certainly start by actually outputting some HTML.

Comment: This is basic PHP. Either put it into an array or spit out HTML. Which part of that do you need help with? Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Downvoters, if you don't like it that n00bs ask questions here, then don't read their questions.  We were all n00bs at some point and all asked stupid questions.  It's a valid question.

Comment: i prefer table...im trying to make it...cant find a way although i dont think it is very hard but my head is dying lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in HTML for Table should do the trick. Although, it's crappy coding to mix PHP and HTML.

```
<?php

require('system/connect.php'); //load the connection file

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `movie`"); // add mysql code to a variable. In this case it will    select ALL columns from the database.

$query = mysql_query($sql); //run the query contained within the variable.

echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //store each single row from the database in an array named $row. While there are any rows left, loop through and execute the following code:

$id = $row['movie_id']; //gets name from DB for a single row
$name = $row['movie_name']; //gets age from DB for a single row
$category = $row['movie_category']; //gets age from DB for a single row

//Following code outputs the data to the webpage:
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>' . $id . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $category . '</td>';

echo '</tr>';

};

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: i wanted to vote +1...but i still dont have 1 rep...anw thnks for ur help :D

Comment: @ouzoumzak If you think this is the right answer, you should be able to hit the green check next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant HTML table? Then it will looks like this

```
<?php

require('system/connect.php'); //load the connection file

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `movie`"); // add mysql code to a variable. In this case it will    select ALL columns from the database.

$query = mysql_query($sql); //run the query contained within the variable.

if (mysql_num_rows($query)) { // if there is some rows in result
    echo "<table>"; // starting HTML table
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //loop through the result                           
       echo "<tr>".
                "<td>".$row['movie_id']."</td>". 
                "<td>".$row['movie_name']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['movie_category']."</td>".
            "</tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>";// finishing HTML table
}
?>
```

**NOTE:** do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.